C# Regular expression string not ending with certain text sequence
I'm searching the pattern for a code like this:
(the whitespace = a dot)

pippo.11.pluto.22.MINNIE      ko
pippo..11..pluto..22..MINNIE  ko
pippo.11.pluto.22.duck        ok
pippo..11..pluto..22..cat     ok

In other words I need a pattern that exlude any string ending with MINNIE and 1 or 2 whitespaces before MINNIE. Upper or lower case are not important.
I try
(pippo\s+\d+(\s){1,2})(pluto\s+\d+(\s){1,2})(?!MINNIE)

but does not work.
Thanks a lot.

Maybe (pippo\s+\d+(\s){1,2})(pluto\s+\d+\b(?!\s+MINNIE)(\s){1,2})? Not sure why you need that many groups though, I'd replace (\s){1,2} with \s{1,2}.

Are the " ok"  and " ko" part of the string?

Why not simply search for .MINNIE$? Maybe with code a bit like if ( ! RegEx.IsMatch( inputString, " MINNIE$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ) { ProcessWanted(inputString); } else { /* Ignoring this case */ }

You may use
(pippo\s+\d+(\s){1,2})(pluto\s+\d+\b(?!\s+MINNIE)(\s){1,2})

where

pluto - matches pluto
\s+ - matches one or more whitespaces
\d+ - matches one or more digits
\b(?!\s+MINNIE) - checks for a word boundary and fails the match if there are one or more whitespaces followed with MINNIE immediately to the right of the current location
(\s){1,2} - matches one or two whitespaces capturing the last one into a group.

